# How to inculde 3d parrty libraries into your module?

Tags: 8

I am using the 3d party php library, and I do not know how to connect. The file structure of my project looks like following:

```
-my_project
--src
---Plugin
----Action
-----MyAction.php
---libs
----mylibs
-----src
------ClassWhichINeed.php

--my_project.info.yml
```

So I need to connect ClassWhichINeed.php to MyAction.php. 
In ClassWhichINeed.php I specified namespace as Drupal\my_project\mylibs;

And in MyAction.php i use Drupal\my_project\mylibs;

But when I create 
$object = new ClassWhichINeed;

I get an error "Undefiened class"

Comment: Use Composer to pull in external dependencies to the project. The autoloader will know how to find them when you add them with `use ...` statements.

Answer (score -1):

suggestion:

in MyAction.php add:

```
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/modules/my_project/src/libs/mylibs/src/ClassWhichINeed.php';
```

Comment: This is not necessary to be doing this in Drupal 8.